# Change background colour and size of UI instantly during long task with Background worker

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, ms-word

I have my main UI as a Window with multiple Control's for multiple pages. When you finish filling in the data on the last page, you'd press "make word document" and it starts making the word document with a background worker. But it has to take a screenshot of a graph on one of the Control 'pages'.

I manage to get that working. And it seems to be resizing as well (so it has the correct size on the document). but it doesn't want to update the background colours and font colours instantly.

I've tried using Application.DoEvents(); I tried using a dispatcher, I even tried sending an action via the backgroundworker.reportprogres() but nothing seems to work.

```
//background worker example

#generating the document#

//not the exact code but this below should be peformed instantly on the ui
MainWindow.height = 720;
MainWindow.Width = 800;
MainWindow.Background= Brush.White;
etc...
//after these are set on the UI

Chart.MakeScreenshot();
```

I've been looking into this problem for months now, but still haven't found a solution. The only way it does work is by using breakpoints.

If needed, I could provide the actual code but I don't have it by hand atm.

Comment: Have you tried `Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => { }));`?

Comment: I tried using Dispatcher.invoke but it didn't seem to update it either. what I did forget to mention is when you're on the Chart page itself, then the colours do change correctly. This is momentarily the only work around, but I can't expect the user to navigate to the chart to generate the word document tbh :/

Comment: Do you run this code on a secondary thread? How did you try to use a dispatcher?

Comment: @the.Doc So I tried it again, just to make sure, but I get an error now saying: "Cannot access non-static method 'Invoke' in static context".

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev It's done with a background worker so technically is in another thread.

Comment: In that case you need to use the dispatcher to schedule any UI changes on the main thread.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I tried the dispatcher with the background worker this time, but no new result It does successfully set the datacontext, changes the size as it should, but ignores the control somehow. only changes the Main Window

Comment: I'd recommend posting what exactly you have tried so far. It is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Update on how my code looks right now. WindowData is in this case the MainWindow.

view in this case is the control

```cs
WindowData.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() =>
{
    WindowData.DataContext = WindowData.GetGraphViewModel();
    ChangeScreen(WindowData, 720, 800);
    System.Windows.WindowState currentWindowStates = WindowData.WindowState;
    WindowData.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
    view.SetGraphReady();
}));
```